# repeat a video a certain number of times

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a video repeat 5 times in one simple page.
The first time it displays normally, but as soon as the video ends I can't get it to start again.

this is my Listener

```
void listenerController() async {
    if (controller.value.isCompleted && (!bVideoController)) {
      bVideoController = true;
      print("completed: ${controller.value.isCompleted}");
      view[indexVideo]++;
      print("Views: ${view[indexVideo]}");
      if (view[indexVideo] < 5) {
        await controller.seekTo(Duration.zero);
        await controller.play();
        print("Re Play -> completed: ${controller.value.isCompleted}");
        print("position video: ${controller.value.position}");
        bVideoController = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

I entered a bit of print to debug and everything appears immediately after the end of the first repetition

> flutter: Views: 1
>
> flutter: Re Play -> completed: false
>
> flutter: position: 0:00:00.000000
>
> flutter: completed: true
>
> flutter: Views: 2
>
> flutter: Re Play -> completed: false
>
> flutter: position: 0:00:00.000000
>
> flutter: completed: true
>
> flutter: Views: 3
>
> flutter: Re Play -> completed: false
>
> flutter: position: 0:00:00.000000
>
> flutter: completed: true
>
> flutter: Views: 4
>
> flutter: Re Play -> completed: false
>
> flutter: posizione: 0:00:00.000000
>
> flutter: position: true
>
> flutter: Views: 5

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand exactly what your code should be doing when half of your variables are in Italian :/

Comment: you are right, sorry